# How can I add a date range and time with a single input to react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I want to create a date range component that will fit both start and end dates along with time input  into a single input component, it tried it but the time input not working properly

```
    const ExampleCustomTimeInput = ({ date, value, onChange }) => (
     <div className="md-form md-outline">
      <input
       type="time"
       id="default-picker"
       className="form-control"
       onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
       placeholder="Select time"
       value={value}
      />
     </div>
    );
```

here is the code

```
                   <DatePicker
                      className="form-control"
                      selected={ingestStartDate}
                      onChange={(date) => {
                        console.log(date);
                        setIngestStartDate(date[0]);
                        setIngestEndDate(date[1]);
                      }}
                      selectsRange
                      startDate={ingestStartDate}
                      endDate={ingestEndDate}
                      showTimeInput
                      customTimeInput={<ExampleCustomTimeInput />}
                      dateFormat="Pp"
                     
                    />
```

Comment: You can check the input value in the onChange callback of the input element and make sure it is within range.

Comment: @MohitKushwaha how can i do that?

Comment: Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-violet-gbjmp?file=/src/App.js